# migrate to git from svn

Tags: git, svn

I want to migrate from svn server to git and completely move to git.

My svn repository contain several folder each one contain difference project.

I cloned the svn repository to git using git svn then i tried to split each of the folders to difference branch using this command:
git subtree split -P name-of-folder -b name-of-new-branch.

The problem is that in some part of the history I mvoed one of the folder to other location and the history in the git repository is keeped only from this position.

I can not see the history even immediately after I run git svn clone

My svn layout is like this:

```
svnrepo/
  folderA/
      projectA files(.sln,.cpp)
  folderB/
      projectB files(.java)
  folder/
      folderC/
          folderC files(.cs)
      folderD/
          folderD files(.cs)
```

I want that will be branch for folder A branch for folderB branch for folderC and branch for folderD.

**edit:**
In some point of my project I moved folderC and folderD like this:

```
   folder/
       web/
          folderC/
              folderC files(.cs)
          folderD/
              folderD files(.cs)
```

Then when I try to clone from the url of folderC I get the history only from the point I moved folderC to web although there was a lot of history before.

Is there any way to save also the history from the previous location?

Comment: Read more about the options to `git svn clone`. It can handle this.

Comment: I already read about git svn clone but I did not find any argument that can help me

Answer (score 0):

[git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) already has options to deal with SVN branches and tags, but they're documented in `init` not `clone`.  `git svn clone` is basically `git svn init` plus `git svn fetch` and takes their options.

For a typical SVN layout...

```
svnrepo/
    trunk/
    branches/
        branch1/
        branch2/
    tags/
        tag1/
        tag2/
```

You can tell git-svn your layout with `--trunk`, `--tags` and `--branches`.  `git svn clone --trunk=trunk/ --tags=tags/ --branches=branches/ <svnurl>`.  There's a shortcut for this standard layout, `--stdlayout`.

For the OP's non-standard layout...

```
svnrepo/
  folderA/
      projectA files(.sln,.cpp)
  folderB/
      projectB files(.java)
  folder/
      folderC/
          folderC files(.cs)
      folderD/
          folderD files(.cs)
```

It would be `git svn --branch=folderA --branch=folderB --branch=folder/folderC --branch=folder/folderD`.  But from the OP's description, these sound more like separate projects, not branches of a single project.  They should be separate Git repositories.

SVN repositories are expensive to setup and maintain, so SVN encourages you to shove unrelated projects into one repository.  Git repositories are super cheap, Git works best when each project is its own repository.  So when you convert, it's best to split each project into its own Git repository.  Then *later* you can stitch related projects together with `git subtree` if you find you need it.

For an SVN repository with multiple projects that you want to turn into multiple Git repositories, simply run `git svn clone` multiple times on each SVN directory, just as you would check them out from SVN.

```
git svn clone https://svn.example.com/folderA/
git svn clone https://svn.example.com/folderB/
git svn clone https://svn.example.com/folder/folderC/
git svn clone https://svn.example.com/folder/folderD/
```

[Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion) has a chapter on converting from SVN to Git that will help more.

Comment: But there is no such folders.the layout of the svn is not organized.
All the folder is in the root of the svn repository and there is no trunk or tags folders in the repository.I want to create them in the new one.

Comment: @amit Are they branches or totally separate projects?

Comment: Basically yes.I add layout of the svn repo

Comment: @amit SVN likes you to shove everything into one repository.  Git works much better if you make a repository for each project. If they're separate projects, create separate Git repositories for them as I've shown in my edits.  *After* you've done that and *only if* they are related, you can create another repository to work with them all together with `git subtree`.  But if they're not related, don't bother.

Comment: But how can I clone with the history from the previous folder that is part of the same project.

Comment: @amit You mean where some files were copied from project to project?  I *think* cloning each project directory separately will handle that.  If it doesn't, LMK and I have more complicated solution that's sure to work.

Comment: Yes.I moved the solution(.sln and all the cpp) couple of times.in the svn history i see many commits but in git I see less commits only from the last folder location

Comment: @amit Is that the result you get from trying to split the projects with `git subtree` or from cloning each project individually?  That is from `git svn clone https://svn.example.com/folderA/` then `git svn clone https://svn.example.com/folderB/` and so on.

Comment: That result is from cloning each project individually.I edit my question.

Comment: I also tried to use -T but I have multiple location and I can not set multiple -T location

Comment: @amit Have you tried treating them all as branches and using `--branches` instead?  This is getting beyond the work I'm willing to put into a free site.  I don't know if it's kosher to solicit work on here, but [I'm available on Codementor.io](https://codementor.io/schwern) if you want to talk a short paid session to work this out.